# Visual Studio Code:[js] types can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to use .js files in a typescript project in vs code? I have clone a react-native project from a github repository and opened it in visual studio code. When I add a tsconfig.json in order to start using typescript,
I get a long list of errors. For example here is a **drawer.js** file (with es6 features):

[image]

Here is my tsconfig.json file (If I remove this file then every thing works fine, no error reported) :

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the '.js' extension, instead of '.ts'?

Comment: As I said I cloned this project from github. It contains tens of .js files code base (es6 syntax). I opened it in vs code and added a tsconfig.json. Typescript is supposed to be a superset of javascript. So I would expect that a .js file should not be a problem in a typescript project.

Comment: Have a look at these threads [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2302) and [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10939). There seems to be an `--allowJS` option that does exactly that: `https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#including-js-files-with---allowjs`. The trick part however is for Visual Code to accept the files... I am not sure if it uses the values of `tsconfig.json` for syntax checking.

Comment: Unfortunately adding allowJS has not solved the problem. I have added "allowJS" in my tsconfig.json file. I'm still having the error

Answer (score 9):

I restarted VS code and the error was gone, just in case it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch, This helped for me :-)

Comment: yeah this work for me too, when starting a project in VSCode, the program preserves the default configs, especially if we add `tsconfig.json` files after open the project.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE - This is just a *WORKAROUND*, not solution. Use *ONLY IF* you do not find appropriate solution**

Workaround - Add the following configuration in `$workspace/.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "javascript.validate.enable": false
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: This simply disables validation completely, which removes the error, but does not solve the larger problem of checking types in JS files.

Comment: It's honestly a bug with react and this is still a valid workaround if you don't want all those "errors"

Comment: Actually, this is the *only* solution I got to work when using a Flow project with VSCode. In that case, Flow takes over the validation. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385231/286685) and specifically the comments on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this!!!

Install in your visual studio code the extension Flow Language Support
and disable TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features

Search @builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features and reload.

You can see this solutions 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859169](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859169/js-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-visual-studio-code-using-ts-check/50385231#50385231)

Its important install npm for flow

[Link Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/)

Answer (score 1):

Has that change the "Select Language Mode" for "TypeScript React" in list. it worked for me.

[image]