# Error: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file - Visual Studio Code using @ts-check

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am starting to use TypeScript in a Node project I am working on in Visual Studio Code. I wanted to follow the "opt-in" strategy, similar to Flow. Therefore I put `// @ts-check` at the top of my `.js` file in hope to enable TS for that file. Ultimately I want the same experience of "linting" as Flow, therefore I installed the plugin [TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) so I could see Intellisense warnings/errors.

But with my file looking like:

```
// @ts-check

module.exports = {
  someMethod: (param: string): string => {
    return param;
  },
};
```

and my `tsconfig.json` file looking like...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2016",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

I get this error: `[js] 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.` as shown below in the image.

[image: error from vscode for ts]

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320266/visual-studio-codejs-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file) which recommended disabling javascript validation in vscode but then that doesn't show me **any** TypeScript Intellisense info.

I tried setting `tslint.jsEnable` to `true` in my vscode settings as mentioned in the TSLint extension docs but no luck there.

What is the correct setup in order to use `.js` files with TypeScript and get Intellisense so I know what the errors in my code are before I run any TS commands?

Comment: Do you have any error if you change the extension to ts?

Comment: @israel.zinc changing the extension to `.ts` show me the TS errors/warnings as expected. I guess this could work, but I was hoping for more of the opt-in method using `@ts-check` while keeping all my extensions as `.js`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code:\[js\] types can only be used in a .ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320266/visual-studio-codejs-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file)

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE it might be, but the answers there did not solve the issue. I mentioned this in my original question.

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726464/2333214

Answer (score 348, accepted):

I'm using [flow](https://flow.org/en/) with vscode but had the same problem.  I solved it with these steps:

1. Install the extension [Flow Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode)
2. Disable the built-in TypeScript extension:

   1. Go to *Extensions* tab
   2. Search for **@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**
   3. Click on *Disable*

Comment: The accepted answer is not always correct. There's a bug in VSCode with React Native and Flow that gives the same message in .js files, and in that case YOU SHOULD NOT change to .ts, but continue with .js and fix the problem as suggested here!!

Comment: Just an FYI:  Disabling this extension basically nullifies all of the nice things about JS development with VSCode.  Instead, you should just add the following into your settings json file:  `"javascript.validate.enable": false`

Comment: as @heez has mentioned this will affect, finding reference to javascript files, autocompletion etc don't disable Javascript Language Features.

Comment: This disables things like going to function definitions.

Comment: The valid answer was said by @heez

Comment: Thanks @heez! when using flow, also `"javascript.validate.enable": false` to get rid of other typescript related validation errors that don't apply

Comment: @heez what is the file name of settings json you are talking about?

Comment: @AnishArya I believe it's called `settings.json`.  You can read more about its default location depending on your platform here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: @heez thanks for the save, I found out. No error now. Can use Visual studio code finally.

Comment: I also had to install that specific version of flow-bin given in .flowconfig file to make that work. Otherwise I just got several errors in my node_modules directory.

Comment: making "javascript.validate.enable": false is not an actual solution but it just hides it, it just doesnt check the file/code. even if you write random/invalid code, vscode will not run into an error. does anyone found the CORRECT resolution?

Answer (score 245):

Use `"javascript.validate.enable": false` in your VS Code settings, It doesn't disable ESLINT. I use both ESLINT & Flow. Simply follow the instructions [Flow For Vs Code Setup](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode#setup)

Adding this line in settings.json. Helps
`"javascript.validate.enable": false`

Comment: With this You don't have to disable typescript. Both can exists. Best solution!

Comment: If you are using ESLint to validate your Javascript, then this answer is the best solution. More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_how-do-i-disable-syntax-validation-when-using-non-es6-constructs and also https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode#setup

Comment: Where can I find settings.json file.?

Comment: Hi @i18n Go to: Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json". Actually find the one under this: `Include Languages
Enable Emmet abbreviations in languages that are not supported by default. Add a mapping here between the language and emmet supported language. E.g.: {"vue-html": "html", "javascript": "javascriptreact"}` click on Edit in settings.json and add this: `"javascript.validate.enable": false`.

Comment: Good solution, note that you can also do this per project/workspace. So you can have normal `typescript` validation in one, and `flow` validation in the other. look for the `Workspace` tab on the settings page.

Comment: To find this in settings (UI), search "javascript validate". It's located under Extensions > Typescript.

Comment: This is not working for my multi-root workspace. When I try to disable that for only one folder, it says: `This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.` ... is it possible to setup with multi-root WS?

Comment: Added a separate question for this ☝️ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346413/setup-flowjs-in-a-vscode-multi-root-workspace-for-only-one-folder

Comment: Before this configuration my `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` startup activation was more than 2500ms now I got 58ms. Thank you It was very helpfull

Answer (score 40):

I followed following steps to fix the issue:

Go to Preferences  and then to settings:
[image: Settings]

After going to settings search for `javascript.validate` in the search bar and uncheck the checkbox:
[image: text in search bar]

if you want to edit it via json then:
Go to: Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json". [image: extension]
then add

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

[image: showing settings.json]

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who lands here and all the other solutions did not work give this a try. I am using typescript + react and my problem was that I was associating the files in vscode as `javascriptreact` not `typescriptreact` so check your settings for the following entries.

```
   "files.associations": {
    "*.tsx": "typescriptreact",
    "*.ts": "typescriptreact"
  },
```

Comment: What file is this?

Comment: This did it for me! (Well, doing this and then reloading the window and restarting the TS language server). Thank you!

Comment: @javaPlease42 Cmd/Ctl Shift F to find stuff in all your project files. files.associations will be in there.

Comment: helped me, thank you so much.

Comment: but why tf is ts associated with javascript ....

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me was adding the following property to **settings.json**:

```
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true
```

> To enable type checking for all JavaScript files without changing any code, just add "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true to your workspace or user settings. This enables type checking for any JavaScript file that is not part of a jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json project.
>
> - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings and search for javascript validate and then disable the option to fix this.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was not initializing my component with `lang="ts"` e.g. `<script setup lang="ts">`

Answer (score 2):

You must use a `.ts` file - e.g. `test.ts` to get Typescript <strike>validation, intellisense</strike> `typing` of vars, return types, as well as "typed" error checking (e.g. passing a `string` to a method that expects an `number` param will error out).

It will be transpiled into (standard) `.js` [via `tsc`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript).

---

### Update (11/2018):

Clarification needed based on down-votes, very helpful comments and other answers.

`types`

- Yes, you can do `type` checking in VS Code in `.js` files with [`@ts-check`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking) - as shown in the animation
- What I originally was referring to for **Typescript** `types` is something like this in `.ts` which isn't quite the same thing:

  `hello-world.ts`

  ```
  function hello(str: string): string {
    return 1;
  }

  function foo(str:string):void{
     console.log(str);
  }
  ```

  **This will not compile. `Error: Type "1" is not assignable to String`**
- if you tried this syntax in a **Javascript** `hello-world.js` file:

  ```
  //@ts-check

  function hello(str: string): string {
    return 1;
  }

  function foo(str:string):void{
     console.log(str);
  }
  ```

  The error message referenced by OP is shown: `[js] 'types' can only be used in a .ts file`

If there's something I missed that covers this as well as the OP's context, please add. Let's all learn.

Comment: I have found a few articles that suggest you can use all the features of TS within a JS file. Here's one from [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/visual-studio-code/#type-check-your-javascript), a [GitHub issue for vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25322) that describes the setup, and some [release notes for vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12#_type-checking-for-javascript-files)

Comment: @jamez14 I haven't tried/had the need to _not_ use `.ts`. IINM, the samples show _error checking_ and _intellisense_. The issue you have is (static) `type`ing your variables, and return `types` as well  - e.g. `foo:string`, `bar:number`, `fubar:MyClass`, `myMethod(f:Array):void`, `anotherMethod():string`. Hth...

Comment: yep, looks like you are right with your assessment. After looking more at the examples, I'm seeing it is just JS error checking, not TS, when using the `@ts-check` attribute. Very misleading...

Comment: Upvoting this because I was dumb in svelte and did not type in the .ts and this generically useful answer helped.

Comment: See this https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs to avoid putting that line in all your js files

Answer (score 2):

[Mac] In your Visual Studio Code type the following command.

- command + shift + P
- Then type " `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`" in the search bar shown on the top of the VS Code
- Add the the line -> `"javascript.validate.enable": false`

Note : "Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)" is non editable

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .svelte, try putting `lang="ts"` in your `<script>` element. Example as below.

```
<script lang="ts">
   ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"typescript.validate.enable": false

IN VS Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> Search for above mentioned property and disable the property

Comment: your safe my life

Answer (score 0):

Types/Interfaces can only be applied to TypeScript files, and .js files are JavaScript files.

So the solution is simple as to:

Change the extension .js to .tsx to use types/interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the built-in TypeScript extension

[follow steps as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bExqv.gif)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34434497)

Answer (score -1):

For VS code in windows, click on settings. Then on the search bar at the top, type javascript validate and just uncheck the checkbox as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just default the variable to the expected type:

```
(number=1) => ...
(number=1.0) => ...
(string='str') ...
```