# How can I fix the error Failed to compile. Type error: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file. TS8008

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, flowtype

I'm using Create React App with Flow, Prettier, ESLint, and Emotion. After installing flow and creating a .babelrc file with `{ "presets": ["flow"] }`, I still get the following compile error when running `yarn start`:

```
Failed to compile. Type error: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file. TS8008
```

That's because I have the following code in `App.jsx`:

```
type PropsType = {
  history: any
};
```

I have another project where I can use `.js` files with flow with no issues, but I can't find why I have this error in this project.

I've also noticed this file being created `src/react-app-env.d.ts` and the contents of .flowconfig being changed by the react-scripts

What am I missing?

Comment: Usually `d.ts` files are Typescript not flow.

Comment: Ok, but I don't have anything related with Typescript installed. It's probably react-scripts doing its thing in the background because it detected flow

Comment: What command did you use to create your CRA application?

Comment: @LyleUnderwood I used this boilerplate: https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/react-fullstack-graphql/tree/master/basic

Comment: If this is VS code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385231/9622392).

Comment: @LyleUnderwood it happens with or without VSCode

Comment: Can you provide a repro repo?