# Setup Flowjs in a VSCode multi-root workspace for only one folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, flow-js

To use Flowjs in VSCode you are supposed to install the [Flow Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) extension and disable the normal JS/TS support either by adding

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

to your projects' VSCode settings.json file or disable the JS/TS-features completely.

I have a multi-root workspace with different project-roots that use JS, TypeScript or FlowJS so I can't disable the JS/TS stuff completely. But disabling JS validation via the folder's vscode settings give me the error/message:

```
This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.
```

And it is not working. None of the Flow-features are working and VSCode complains about things like this:

```
- 'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.
- Type aliases can only be used in TypeScript files.
- Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.
- ...
```

How can I get FlowJS + VSCode working when I'm using a multi-root workspace?

Example project:

```
Project
├──Root A (plain old JS)
│  └───.vscode
│      └─── settings.json
│
├──Root B (FlowJS)
│  └───.vscode
│  │   └─── settings.json  // "javascript.validate.enable": false
│  └─── test.js            // error: Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)
│
├──Root C (TypeScript)
│  └───.vscode
│      └─── settings.json
│
└─── example.code-workspace
```

Comment: This may help you: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces