# Click Element in Selenium Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am automating a website in which I want to click on the x when a subscription popup comes up
The HTML for the X is

```
<button title="Close popup message" data-testid="email-popup-close-button" id="email-popup-close-button" class="dw-1hfj58t-CloseBtn--EmailContainer e1lwf35p0">×</button>
```

So to click on this I am using the below

```
await driver.findElement(By.id("email-popup-close-button")).click();
```

But it is coming up with the below error

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="email-popup-close-button"]"}
```

[image: Screenshot attached here]

Comment: Are you trying to access the element before it exists?

Comment: @epascarello that's what I'm beginning to wonder, if you could assist with js code so it makes it wait until the element is there that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer
Declared this
`const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require("selenium-webdriver");`

and used

```
let query = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('email-popup-close-button')));
    await query.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue with locator. Give a try to below.

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[normalize-space()='×'])[1]")).click();
```

***Or***

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Close popup message']")).click();
```

***Or***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@title='Close popup message']")));
elem.click();
```

***Import:***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @akzy
I have tried your xpath, full xpath -  /html/body/aside[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button, the xpath chrome gives me - //*[@id="email-popup-close-button"], the className, id and same issue

I have tried the second answer and it says wait is no defined - unsure how to define this (I am very new to JS)

Before this pop up there is another to accept cookies, which i have selected using className, so unsure why this is different and not working

Comment: Have checked the above ?

Comment: I have added the import too.

Comment: @Hannah - I have checked this using this URL https://www.dunelm.com/ and the solution with wait is working for me. I have added all the required import as well. Try the last solution

Comment: Really appreciate the help, when putting the different imports in, it says can only be used in typescript files, do you know the javascript equivalent please?

Comment: Can you share the code and error, actually I tested all this with Java

Comment: When i add the imports in like the above, it says 'import..=; can only be used in TypeScript files

Comment: Can you check this to disable it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68441308/11863448