# React js typescript not working in sub folders

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript with react js. Typescript is working when creating tsx files in src folder. But whenever I am using tsx in a sub folder like ex. components folder typescript is not working.

> tsconfig.json:

```
{"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx" }, "include": ["src"] }
```

Comment: Can you try adding "baseUrl": "src" to the tsconfig.json file and try it.

Comment: Nothing changed after adding baseUrl. Still getting "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files" error in vscode whenever using type annotations in tsx files in sub folder.

Comment: Can you review this resource? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859169/error-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-visual-studio-code-using-ts-che

Answer (score 0):

look at newly generated tsconfig using

for web

> npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

for react native

> npx react-native init MyApp --template
> react-native-template-typescript

check the dir on your top imports, when using vscode, there's also an auto suggestion feature when you type component name

Hope it helps